# How do I destroy a duouniversal shield?

Tags: universe

First, I'll explain what a duouniversal rock is.

It's a rock that exists in two alternate universes, and always interact with each other, therefore making it virtually indestructible, only by destroying both at the exact same time.

But as a shield, there is not telling when it is going to die.

So how would I destroy it?

Comment: How did you make a shield out of an indestructible rock?

Comment: @Frostfyre I think it was found like that

Comment: Is this an object you created, or are you asking about an object in a game?

Comment: @Frostfyre I created it... its our own words we're building, right?

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to make sure. Since you created the object, what rules have you set regarding is destruction? This seems to be a job for handwavium, regardless.

Comment: Why do the rules for its destruction change when it's a shield?

Comment: Shields don't break so easily.

Comment: @bleh "Shield" is a moniker given to describe useful properties of an object.  It does not actually convey any new physical properties.  If the "shield" doesn't break easily, then the rock doesn't break easily -- in fact, they should break with exactly the same level of ease, because the name does not change the thing.  At least, that is unless you're in a world where belief imbues properties (such as the Orkish belief that painting a vehicle with red paint makes it go faster actually causes red Orkish vehicles to go faster).  If so, that would be an important detail to put into the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Could God create a rock so heavy...

One of the challenges we face in Worldbuilding is when we deal with absolutes.  You have a rock that is unbreakable.  The Juggernaut can't be stopped once he starts moving.  Aliens bring us a source of unlimited energy.  These ultimate extremes are appealing because they appear to bring excitement to the universe which doesn't exist in the real world.

Unfortunately, we often find that our ultimate creation is too ultimate, and we need to create something that can defeat it.  The only problem is that you've already woven a *ton* of handwavium style arguments into your creation.  You're not satisfied with any easy solution.  Your awesome creation has become your biggest pain in the rear!

The first step is to remember that this is *your* handwavium, by *your* rules.  You can change your rules.  You say:

> It's a rock that exists in two alternate universes, and always interact with each other, therefore making it virtually indestructible, only by destroying both at the exact same time.

You've intentionally created something that, by that exact wording, cannot be destroyed within one universe.  That was your wording.  You penned it, you chose to live by it.  It shapes your world, and ironically becomes as unbreakable as your duouniversal shield itself.

You can choose to change that rule, so that there is a way to destroy it, or you have to only focus on solutions that work in both universes.  This is basic logic.  It's hard to compete with logic when you were the one who wrote the assumptions.

We're going to have to look at how connected the two universes are.  If there's no communication between the two universes, so it would be impossible to coordinate an effort to break the shield on both sides, then you have written yourself into a corner, and you can sit in it.  Your duouniversal rock is now stronger than the entirety of the rest of both universes combined.  How can you fit that into your story?  Can you make it a focal point?

Perhaps we can allow more communication between the universe.  After all, we have a rock that's in both universes, why not other things?  Perhaps we could have something which exists in both universes and causes something to vibrate in opposite directions in the two universes.  Symmetrical devices like that are always interesting. You might be able to use it to cause one rock to vibrate one direction, one rock to vibrate the other, and in the regions where the rock is no longer overlapping in both dimensions, chip away at it like normal rock.

In the end, its up to you to invent handwavium to combat your own handwavium when it gets you into trouble.  There is no one answer: there is at least one answer for every ruleset you consider for resolving your handwavium troubles.  Go explore, and find what is best for you!

Comment: I think the last paragraph of your answer adequately proves that this question is too broad/opinion based.

Comment: @Aify: But it is tempting to re-word the question so that it is good and this a useful canonical answer. Something like "In my world-building, I keep creating *ultimate* objects (- insert shield as example -), and then cannot find a way to rein them in. What am I doing wrong?" Also, refer http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SerialEscalation

Comment: @NeilSlater Actually, I think a question like that would belong more on Writers.SE, not WB.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to destroy it? It's just a big rock. You can teleport past it, or shoot straight through it with x-ray lasers, or just circle round the shield and attack from the other side. If there's somebody hiding behind the shield, presumably they have gun ports or breathing holes or something, and you can attack through those. Or you can just shove the whole thing into some lava (or the sun, if this is a space game) -- that won't destroy it but it'll melt whatever's inside.

If you do have to destroy it, you've already described the way to do it: get on your duouniversal radio, contact somebody in that other universe, and get them to attack it with you. With any luck, there's an alternate-you in that alternate-universe who also wants to destroy that rock, and they're trying to contact you so you can coordinate on when to strike.

Answer (score 0):

Are other ways of destroying the shields acceptable?

Can you bring the other shield into the same universe in order to destroy them simultaneously?  If they are united, you can guarantee being able to destroy them at the same time.

If only one shield can exist in a given universe, like in ["The Alternative Factor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alternative_Factor) episode of Star Trek, can you trap or move the shield in a third dimension so it no longer effects yours?  This will move the problem to a different universe while you deal with whatever was behind the shield.  As a nice guy, you can even replace the shield once you're done circumventing it.

Comment: No, because when they interact with each other, the cant be brought together, or both universes have to collide with each other.